# Unit testing of non-atomic methods

Tags: programming-practices, unit-testing

I'm new in unit testing. For last two days I'm thinking how to test non-atomic methods with unit tests. 
When i need to write tests for some simple, atomic method situation in pretty easy - i'm taking all scenarios for this method that i can imagine,  and reforge each of it in unit test.

But what if i have methods that are calling other methods? Should I test each scenarios for tested method AND each methods it is calling?

Maybe some example will be easier to understand:

```
    public int makeSomeOperation(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a < 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("a must be greater that 0");
        if (b == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("b cannot be 0");
        return a/b;
    }

    public bool SomeNonatomicMethod(int number)
    {
        if (number * number % 2 == 1)
            return false;
        int secondNumber = getNumberFromMordor();
        int result = makeSomeOperation(number, secondNumber);
        if (result == "123")
            return true;
        return false;
    }
```

In this case, `makeSomeOperation` is easy to test - one test for each exception, one to check in returning result is equals with expectations.

But what about SomeNonatomicMethod? Did I need to write not only test for each case in this method (so: power of number is odd, result is equal 123, and result is diffrent), but also each possible flow of things that may happen in `getNumberFromMordor` and `makeSomeOperation`?

Things that may happen in `makeSomeOperation` are already tested, so are they should be tested second time?

Comment: I believe the term you are looking for is "referentially transparent," rather than "atomic."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If `getNumberFromMordor` and `makeSomeOperation` are public, they should be tested by themselves, so your unit test should not doublecheck that `getNumberFromMordor` works correctly.

Only test what `SomeNonatomicMethod` does. Don't re-test public methods it relies on.

If `getNumberFromMordor` is private, you should test `SomeNonatomicMethod` against the possibility that `getNumberFromMordor` fails to work properly.

If `SomeNonatomicMethod` itself does so many things that you end up with dozens of assertions, it is a signal that it doesn't follow the single responsibility principle and should be broken down.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would not test the "makeSomeOperation" method.  **However**, this is not a universal rule.  Why?  Because your composite method may not supply an adequate combination of parameters to execute all of "makeSomeOperation"'s code.

So, what you're *really* looking for is code coverage.  When you write unit tests, and you've got a good code coverage tool, once you get to somewhere between 80% and 90% code coverage for a large library, you're doing pretty good.  Ideally you'd get 100%, but that's almost impossible to maintain on a code base of any size.  Maybe if the code you were writing was running in a medical device or something you'd try to maintain 100%, but for we mere mortals, we try to target and maintain 80% to 90% code coverage.